# Parallel variable selection in R using foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

In the provided example , I have  a response variable Y=599*1 and  X =1279 * 599 marker. We need to use variable selection “ backward and froward selection” to select the most significant markers.

I tried to use several methods to do that, unfortunately all of them take too much time to finish.

So,  I thought to split X to sub data sets= #of cores in my computer, using k-means ()  then pass all the clusters “data sets” using foreach () in parallel to the variable selection method.

My expect outputs should be marker names and regression coefficients for the select markers. 
I will be so grateful if you have a better idea to solve my current problem or help me  parallel it using foreach.

here is an example:

```
 library(BLR)

 data(wheat)

 a <- regsubsets(as.matrix(X),Y[,1],really.big=T) 
 ## is there is a better way to do that?
```